# Can't free up HD space

Tags: hard-drive, nautilus, disk-usage, storage

Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS

Got to 0 bytes of HD space.

Couldn't boot.

Used a live disk boot USB thing.

Used nautilus.

Deleted files of 4gb but didn't free up space+ nothing in the rubbish folder.

Googled and someone said use shift + delete within nautilus. Tried. Agreed I wanted permanent deletion. Still 0 bytes.

1. Please how can I get it to not display 0 bytes?
2. I deleted quite a few files initially. Later , how can I get the Ubuntu to mark them as deleted ?

Comment: It is unclear haw many partitions you have and where are you deleting files from.

Comment: I just have one 256gb internal HD that is 0 bytes. I access it from a live usb stick. @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

`df`, `du` and `rm`  are you best friends. Nautilus most likely deletes the "data" into another "Trash" directory which is most likely `~/.local/share/Trash/`

Comment: The trash folder you mentioned is empty, plus I permanently deleted the files. Ok I'll investigate those commands you suggested. @mestia

Comment: df -h lists says 100% of drive is used and 0 is available. However the size says 234G and Used 225G. I deleted some files using rm but still says 0 bytes, however the used size in df did decrease.@mestia

Comment: check `/var/log` directory, like `du -sh /var/log`, another potentially interesting file is `/home/<youruser>/.xsessions-errors` sometimes it can grow a lot due to a buggy application(s)

Answer (score 0):

You need 5% free on the HD before it will stop displaying 0 bytes.